# DDOS Attack on WHM with CentOS 6

Tags: linux, apache, bash, tcp, awk

I have the following command to get the current IPs connected:

```
netstat -ntu | awk '{print $5}' | egrep -o -e '[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*' | sort | uniq -c  | awk '{if ($1 > 50) print $2" # "$1" times."}' | sort -n
```

When I ran the above command will get the following results:

```
68.4.90.74 # 185 times.
77.42.241.230 # 258 times.
78.40.177.38 # 658 times.
79.171.81.237 # 798 times.
79.172.252.26 # 435 times.
```

run this to get details of on of the above IPs

```
netstat -noap | grep 68.4.90.74
```

will give you (simple of):

```
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80          68.4.90.74:56484            ESTABLISHED 10561/httpd         keepalive (6398.07/0/0)
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:53          68.4.90.74:56480            ESTABLISHED 10519/httpd         keepalive (6379.57/0/0)
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:53          68.4.90.74:56481            ESTABLISHED 9817/httpd          keepalive (6379.56/0/0)
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:53          68.4.90.74:56483            ESTABLISHED 9838/httpd          keepalive (6379.56/0/0)
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80          68.4.90.74:56482            ESTABLISHED 10505/httpd         keepalive (6379.34/0/0)
```

My Question is how  to update the first code to get the IPs connected through none of port 80  Although the following code can be get the IPs connected via specific port:

```
netstat -ntu | awk '/\:80\ / {print $5}' | egrep -o -e '[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*' | sort | uniq -c  | awk '{if ($1 > 50) print $2" # "$1" times."}' | sort -n
```

Comment: So you want only the connections *not* on port 80?

Comment: Exactly, this is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

This awk script does most of the work for you:

```
netstat -ntu | awk '/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/ && !($5 ~ /:80$/){split($5,a,":");++seen[a[1]]}END{for(i in seen)print i, "#", seen[i], "times."}'
```

The first pattern is similar to yours but I have used `+` rather than `*` to match one or more digits. The second pattern ensures that the 5th field does not end in `:80`. Only process lines that match the first pattern but not the second.

Split the 5th field into the array `a` and keep a count of all IP addresses in the array `seen`. At the end, loop through all elements in `seen` and print the output.